# The rownum and alignment order do not work as desired

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't want to be an order by channel ID.
All I want is order by book_date for the entire channel.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT CAST(@rownum := @rownum +1 AS signed integer) AS row_cnt  
        , id /* index */ 
        , CASE WHEN 0 < (SELECT count(*) FROM cmsDB.g_room_type WHERE name = t1.room_type AND chanel_mgt_id = t1.chanel_mgt_id) THEN '정상' ELSE '비매칭' END AS status  
        , DATE_FORMAT(book_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS book_date 
        , room_type 
        , (SELECT info.room_name FROM cmsDB.g_room_info info, cmsDB.g_room_type tp WHERE info.id = tp.room_info_id AND tp.name = t1.room_type AND tp.chanel_mgt_id = t1.chanel_mgt_id GROUP BY info.room_name) AS room_name 
        , DATEDIFF(check_out_date,check_in_date) AS night_cnt 
        , check_in_date 
        , check_out_date 
        , room_num 
        , book_name 
        , phone_num 
        , book_num 
        , reg_book_num 
        , deposit_price 
        , book_status 
        , client_status 
        , sub_chanel_sort 
        , t2.companyNm AS company_name 
        , t1.remarks 
        , t1.night_date 
        , t1.reg_status 
        , chanel_mgt_id 
        , (SELECT sort.name FROM cmsDB.g_chanel_sort sort WHERE sort.id = t2.chanelSortId) AS chanelName 
    FROM 
        cmsDB.e_cl_book_themoum t1 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                cm.id AS chanelMgtId
                , ci.name AS companyNm, cm.chanel_sort_id AS chanelSortId 
            FROM cmsDB.g_chanel_mgt cm, cmsDB.g_company_info ci 
            WHERE cm.company_info_id = ci.id) t2 
            ON t2.chanelMgtId = t1.chanel_mgt_id 
            , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
            WHERE 1=1 AND t1.chanel_mgt_id in ( 49 , 50 , 56 , 69 , 70 , 71 ) 
            ORDER BY t1.book_date asc 
    ) tbl ORDER BY 1 desc LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

If you do this, the results will be...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B6Qi.png

This is the result.

But the result I want is the date order for the entire channel_id.

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of order by 1  based on column position in select clause (first column on select )

You should use  an explicit order by using column  name

```
ORDER BY book_date desc LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

or

```
ORDER BY chanel_mgt_id, book_date desc LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

if you want also the row_cnt   then add the column name in the position you need

```
ORDER BY chanel_mgt_id, book_date, row_cnt    desc LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

Comment: Thank you!
But there's one more problem.
The ROWNUM's not aligned.
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Your comment is not clear .. anyway answer  updated . with a suggestion